# Sum of values for specific key in a list of dictionaries python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

I've got a list of dictionaries:

```
[({'symbol':symbol, 'name':name, 'shares_total':shares_total, 'price':price, 'holding_value':holding_value})
 ({'symbol':symbol, 'name':name, 'shares_total':shares_total, 'price':price, 'holding_value':holding_value})
 etc.
]
```

I want to introduce a variable `holdings_total` which is the sum of values for all `"holding_value"` keys in a list of dictionaries.

I believe there is some succinct method, but cannot figure it out.

Could someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#lst = list of dicts

sum_hold = sum(d.get('holding_value', 0) for d in lst)
```

In case the dict does not have the `holding_value` key